# How can a Java sub class respond to an event in the super class?

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm building an Android app that has 3 activities;

1. MainActivity
2. DetailsActivity
3. MapActivity

And a helper class called `DataRequester` that grabs data from my online database.

For performance sake when my app starts, in MainActivity I prefetch (using the DataRequester) two lists of custom objects from my online database and store them in a singleton StateManager class.  This way when the user goes to the MapActivity we do not need to reload the same lists data again.

I have a method in all 3 activities that looks for the data, and loads it if needed, using the `DataRequester` class.  The data is returned in a callback.

Here's my problem.  I have the same code in 3 different activities and I want to keep my code DRY, I thought it would be best to consolidate the code in a BaseActivity class and have all three of my activities extend that base class.  So I moved all the duplicate code to the base class, *including the callback method*...and now I'm stuck.  This important fetching my data work is happening in my super/base class...but the sub class activity is not aware of it.  The callback is happening in the super class.

How can I have the downloading code in my super class and yet have some sort of callback fire in a sub class?  What is the best approach to solve this coding dilemma?

Comment: Other than moving the interface back, your options are adopting some library like RxAndroid and/or EventBus/Otto

Answer (score 0):

You can use of method overriding here:

**BaseActivity** : You can make it `abstract` since anyways you won't be instantiating it.

```
void onDataReceived() {
    actOnData();
}

abstract void actOnData();
```

**ChildActivity1 extends BaseActivity**

```
@Override
void actOnData() {
    // Act differently based on ChildActivity1 requirements.
}
```

**ChildActivity2 extends BaseActivity**

```
@Override
void actOnData() {
    // Act differently based on ChildActivity2 requirements.
}
```

Comment: So if the Super class calls actOnData(Object myObject) and the sub class overrides actOnData it will get passed the object?  I was assuming the super class could only send data to its own methods and not its children

Comment: Since you make the super class abstract, the object of it cannot be created. Object created will be of child class. Super class can call that abstract method in its own class whose implementation is defined by the class whose object is currently instantiated.